# Getting empty data in localstorage in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, jsx

**When I click on submit button, I should get data in my local storage but my array of objects is completely empty**

I am assigning value to localArray variable using titleDesMap variable and I am getting data on it but not getting in local storage.

I am not getting any suitable answer for my question.

Can anyone please help...?

```
class Body extends React.Component {
  titleDescMap = new Map();
  localArray = new Array();
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeTitle = this.handleChangeTitle.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeDescription = this.handleChangeDescription.bind(this);
    this.handleCheckBoxChange = this.handleCheckBoxChange.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    countTodo: 1,
    valueTitle: "",
    valueDescription: "",
    checkStatus: false,
    routeLoading: false,
    localStorageData: {},
  };

  statesStatus() {
    return {
      checkStatus: this.state.checkStatus,
    };
  }

  handleChangeTitle(event) {
    this.setState({
      valueTitle: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  handleChangeDescription(event) {
    this.setState({
      valueDescription: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  handleCheckBoxChange(event) {
    this.setState((prev) => ({ checkStatus: !prev.checkStatus }));
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ routeLoading: true });

    var previousTitle = this.titleDescMap.has(this.state.valueTitle);

    // Sending data to database

    // Checking if any title and desc is previously stored
    if (previousTitle) {
      alert("Please Enter Another Title (which you have never used)");
    } else {
      // Setting the values in title and description into Map
      this.titleDescMap.set(this.state.valueTitle, this.state.valueDescription);

      // Updating id as counter increases 1
      const todoData = await axiosURL.get("/todo-data").then((res) => {
        this.setState({ routeLoading: true });
        return res.data;
      });
      this.setState({ routeLoading: false });
      this.setState({
        countTodo: todoData[todoData.length - 1].countTodo + 1,
      });

// Starts here

        this.localArray.push(this.titleDescMap);
        localStorage["localStorageData"] = JSON.stringify(this.localArray);
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage["localStorageData"]));
        console.log(this.localArray);

//Ends here

      }
    this.props.history.push("/submit");
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.routeLoading) {
      return (
        <div className="spinner-design-outer">
          <SpinnerRoundOutlined
            className="spinner-design-inner"
            color="#337AB7"
            size="100px"
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="body-container">
        <p className="body-direction">Fill To Save Your Todo</p>
        <form method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Title here"
              value={this.state.valueTitle}
              onChange={this.handleChangeTitle}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Description</label>
            <br />
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Description here"
              rows="4"
              cols="40"
              value={this.state.valueDescription}
              onChange={this.handleChangeDescription}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-check">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              className="form-check-input"
              onChange={this.handleCheckBoxChange}
            />
            <label className="form-check-label body-input-label">
              Save Permanently
            </label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            + Add
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Body);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local storage can't be mutated directly like that. It behaves more like JS `Map`, with `getItem` getter and `setItem` setter:

```
// Change this
localStorage["localStorageData"] = JSON.stringify(this.localArray);

// to this
localStorage.setItem("localStorageData", JSON.stringify(this.localArray));

// log like that
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localStorageData")));
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

EDIT:

The other problem is that you are trying to serialize (`JSON.stringify()`) an array which contains a `Map` data structure. It seems it does't work this way (JSON doesn't support `Map`s – it converts them to empty objects): you need to convert the `Map` to an array first (see https://2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html):

```
// change this
this.localArray.push(event.this.titleDescMap);

// to this
this.localArray.push([...event.this.titleDescMap]);
```

When you get your data from a `localStorage`, you'll probably need to convert this array back to a `Map`.

Comment: I did it but still, I am getting the same problem. Getting the data on my console but it is not storing me in local storage. It is showing an empty array of object.

Comment: You're right, there is another issue (serializing JS `Map` to JSON). I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ok Done, but everytime I refresh page and enter data. The localstorage stores the newest data not pushing it in previous one.

Comment: You need to get the current array from localStorage, parse it, push the new item into the parsed array and then save it to localStorage again. Currently, you are always pushing one item into newly created `localArray`, then save it as `localStorageData` – thus overwriting the previous contents.